# Complex analysis on real integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Use complex analysis to compute the real integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^3}$$

## Attempt

I think I want to consider this as the real part of

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dz}{(1+z^2)^3}$$

and then apply the residue theorem. However, I am not sure how that is the complex form and the upper integral is the real part and how to apply.

Comment: Whether you interpret the variable as a real or a complex variable shouldn't change the value of the integral. So the real integral isn't the real part of the complex integral, it is _equal_ to the complex integral, which shouldn't have an imaginary part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a contour that is a semicircle in the upper half plane of radius R.  Plus the real line from $-R$ to $R$

Then let R get to be arbitrarily large.

There is one pole at $z = i$ inside the contour

Cauchy integral formula says:

$$f^{(n)}(a) = \frac {n!}{2\pi i}\oint \frac {f(a)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\ dz$$

$$\oint \frac {\frac {1}{(z+i)^3}}{(z-i)^3}\ dz = \pi i \frac{d^2}{dz^2} \frac {1}{(z+i)^3} \text{ evaluated at } z=i.$$

Next you will need to show that the integral along contour of the semi-cricle goes to $0$ as $R$ gets to be large.

$$z = R e^{it}, dz = iR e^{it}\\
\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi} \frac {iRe^{it}}{(R^2 e^{2it} + 1)^3} \ dt\\
\left|\frac {iRe^{it}}{(R^2 e^{2it} + 1)^3}\right| < R^{-5}\\
\left|\int_0^{\pi} \frac {iRe^{it}}{(R^2 e^{2it} + 1)^3} \ dt\right| < \int_0^{\pi} R^{-5}\ dt\\
\lim_\limits{R\to \infty}\int_0^{\pi} R^{-5}\ dt = 0$$

Comment: What do you mean by the contour of the semi-cricle goes to 0 as R gets to be large? That it essentially becomes a straight line?

Comment: @az89 I have put in an update that should answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

At a first glance this looks like something that can be solved using the method of contour integration. If we consider a semicircle in the upper half plane with radius $R$, we see that in this region, the function $\dfrac{1}{(1+z^2)^3}$ has a pole at $z=i$, so the residue theorem states that the integral taken "around" the semicircle should be $2\pi i$ times the residue at $z=i$.
If you can then compute the integral around the semicircle "without" the real axis, you should be able to get the value of your integral, as we let $R\to \infty$.

Does this help?

Comment: It does but I'm having trouble calculating the residue.

Answer (score 2):

In order to perform such an integration, you **need** to specify a specific **contour** over which you're integrating, since the singularities of the integrating function vary.

**A standard way of solving such integrals is :**

The singularities of the integrating function :

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^3}$$

come as : $x^2 + 1 = 0 \Rightarrow x=\pm i$.

We will integrate the function $f(x)$ with respect to $x$, over the partially smooth curve that is consisted of the half-moon of the upper level of $γ_R$, with $z(θ) = Re^{iθ}$, $0 \geq θ \geq π$ and the line segment $[-R,R]$, where we take $R$ to be big enough, so that the singularity points $(x=i)$ in the upper plane are inside $γ_R$.

From the ***Residue-Theorem*** we have :

$$\int_{-R}^R \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^3}\,dx + \int_{γ_R}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^3} \, dz = 2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f(x),i)$$

The function also satisfies ***Jordan's Lemma***, so it is :

$$\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{γ_R}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^3}=0$$

thus :

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^3} \, dx=\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{-R}^R \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^3} \, dx= 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}(f(x),i)$$

I'll leave the residue calculation to you!

Answer (score 2):

It is much faster to apply Feynman's trick. For any $a>0$ we clearly have
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{a+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a}} \tag{1} $$
and by applying $\frac{d^2}{da^2}$ to both sides:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{2\,dx}{(a+x^2)^3} = \frac{3\pi}{4a^2\sqrt{a}} \tag{2} $$
hence by evaluating $(2)$ at $a=1$ we instantly get
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^3}\,dx = \frac{3\pi}{8}\tag{3}$$
and in general
$$ \forall m\geq 1,\qquad \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^{m}}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{4^{m-1}}\binom{2m-2}{m-1}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: I don't think that Feynman's trick was intended as solution for this problem. But nice to see it in action. (+1)

Comment: Let's keep it real, guys, this integral was shouting very loud for Feynman's trick. Someone had to do it!! Nice (+1)

Answer (score 1):

First we try to make a complex integral. Suppose we wanna solve:

$$\int{dz\over{(1+z^2)^3}}$$

when $z$ moves on curvature $C$ with below definition:

$C:$

$-R\le z\le R$ when $z\in \Bbb R$

$$z=Re^{i\theta} \text{ and } 0\le \theta\le\pi$$

i.e. $C$ is a semicircle of radius $R$ on the positive half-plane of $\Bbb C$. then we can break the complex integral to two as following:

$$ \int{dz\over{(1+z^2)^3}}=\int_{-R}^{R}{dx\over{(1+x^2)^3}}+\int_{0}^{\pi}{{iRe^{i\theta}d\theta}\over{(1+R^2e^{2i\theta})^3}}$$

Using complex analysis:

$$\int_{C}{dz\over{(1+z^2)^3}}={2\pi i\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}{Res_{C}(z_i)}}$$

where $Res(z_i)$ indicates on residue of $f(z)={1\over{(1+z^2)^3}}$ in singularity $z_i$ included by $C$. Since for our function the only such singularity is $z=i$ for sufficiently large $R$ we the obtain:

$$\int_{C}{dz\over{(1+z^2)^3}}={2\pi i\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}{Res_{C}(i)}}$$

where $Res_{C}(i)$ has been calculated as follows:

$$Res_{C}(i)={1\over 2!}{lim_{z\to i}{{{d^2}\over{dz^2}}}{{(z-i)^3}{1\over{(1+z^2)^3}}}}={{-3\over 16}i}$$

since the singularity is of order 3 by factorizing ${1\over{(1+z^2)^3}}$ to ${1\over{(z+i)^3(z-i)^3}}$. Then the complex integral would be:

$$\int_{C}{dz\over{(1+z^2)^3}}=(2\pi i)({{-3\over 16}i})={3\pi\over 8}$$

With $R\to\infty$ the second term of right side tends to zero, because order of $R$ in denominator is greater than that of numerator therefore:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty {dx\over{(1+x^2)^3}}={3\pi \over 8}$$

Comment: "using complex analysis" is a little broad, no?